# How to pass user through login view to safe page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

I have AccountController as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string user_name,string password)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var x = (from n in db.Customers
                 where n.User_Name==user_name && n.Password==password                         
                 select n).FirstOrDefault();
        if (x != null)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = x.First_Name;                                        
            return RedirectToAction("Products","Home");
        }
        else
        {
            @ViewBag.ErrorValidationFailed = "Invalid username or password";                    
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

And HomeController

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    //Some code here
}
```

Now what should I do, once the verifying the credentials? I want the user to get access to the action methods in the HomeController. But after verifying credentials instead of redirecting to Products action method it says 401 Error. Plz correct me if I am wrong anywhere within

Comment: You use attribute [Authorize], but not authenticate user. For example FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(x.First_Name, false); if you build your app with form authentication

Comment: @IgorSemin then how to restrict the user not to access action methods within HomeController and how to allow a user to access the same once he is verified.

Comment: very simple, just authenticate him!

Comment: @IgorSemin like if I does the above way I am unable to access Action Methods within HomeController. Plz specify how u mean it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches for doing this.

### 1st Approach:

one way  is making a base controller and inherit your controllers from base which need authenticated user:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "LogOut", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
            else
                filterContext.Result =  new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
        }

    }
}
```

and then inherit HomeController from BaseController:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{ 

}
```

### 2nd Approach:

Second Approach is to create a Custom Action Filter Attribute and decorate your actions with it that need authentication:

```
public class AuthenticateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "LogOut", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
            else
                filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
}
```

and decorate your action with the attribute which actions should be accessed by authenticated user:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult AllowAllUserAction()
   {

   } 
   [Authenticate]
   public ActionResult SomeAction()
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: But how if I want an action method within HomeController to be anonymous then how should that be done. I tried using AllowAnonymous attribute on the action method and it doesn't work

Comment: can you show by updating your question how are you doing

Comment: I am using the first approach and within my HomeController I am having multiple action method. Things works fine when I use first approach I have to login to access any of the action methods

Comment: but now I want to allow the Index action within HomeController to be accessed by anonymous users also.Then I used AllowAnonymous above the action method but I am redirect to login page

Comment: If I use the second approach then within the AuthenticateAttribute class I am getting error as 'The Name RedirectToAction' does not exist in the current context

Comment: using 2nd approach you have to use ``RediectResult`` like this: ``filterContext.Result =  new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");``

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it should work

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string user_name,string password)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var x = (from n in db.Customers
                 where n.User_Name==user_name && n.Password==password                         
                 select n).FirstOrDefault();
        if (x != null)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = x.First_Name;    

            //Authenticating the user  
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(x.First_Name, false);

            return RedirectToAction("Products","Home");
        }
        else
        {
            @ViewBag.ErrorValidationFailed = "Invalid username or password";                    
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials();


        credentials.Username = formCollection["username"].ToString();
        credentials.Password = formCollection["password"].ToString();
        var result = ApiHelper.PostLogin<FRP.WebApp.Models.Credentials>(MicroService.Login, "/api/Authenticate/Login", credentials, credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
        ViewData["username"] = formCollection["username"];
        ViewData["password"] = formCollection["password"];

        if (result.Status == Sonata.Framework.Models.BusinessStatus.Ok)
        {
            ViewData["error"] = "";
            return View("About", result);
        }
        else
        {
            RegistrationViewModel model = new RegistrationViewModel();
            model.Years = ViewHelper.GetYears();
            ViewData["error"] = "InValid";
            return View("Index",model);
        }
    }
```